# Is there an easy way to handle forms with PHP?

Tags: php, forms, character, punctuation

Dealing with forms in PHP has always given me major headaches. Primarily formatting; handling punctuation inside a form input, manipulating strings for database insertions, stripping when retrieving from database, etc.

Is there an easy alternative to strip_slashes and all that junk? I don't want a tool like a form wizard that does everything for you - I still would like a high level of customization. What would be nice though is a tool that says "I want this text field to connect to this database field.", then it handles all that tedious work.

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.formtools.org/

Comment: Use prepared statements, ideally learn to use PDO and you don't have to deal with slashes and "all that junk"

Comment: nothing will replace doing the work yourself, psychic_php($guess)

Comment: Just create helper functions that you can reuse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is therea better way to in Dealing with forms in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841342/is-therea-better-way-to-in-dealing-with-forms-in-php)

Comment: That's really weird. That wasn't me, but I can see why you would think that (he even used the same terminology). Anyways, thanks for your help guys. I'm not a big fan of CakePHP, but will give the other suggestions a try.

Answer (score 0):

**Look up [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).**  It makes it quite nice to handle all of the database stuff.  As for mapping forms. . . You'd need another application (if one exists out of the box) to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into PHP frameworks which are specifically designed to support systems involving user input.

Personally I've used CakePHP and it's been very useful (though it does tend to assume you have a fairly simple data model and you don't mind creating it from scratch). It's highly customisable (you create all form components yourself) and if you use its full capabilities it will handle slashes and database fields and all the rest.

Other frameworks are available...