# Is therea better way to in Dealing with forms in PHP

Tags: php, forms

I hate working with forms in PHP has always given me problems. As in formatting; handling punctuation inside a form input, manipulating strings for database insertions and so on. I also don't like that the form wizard that does everything for you - but I still would like a high level of customization. Help?

Comment: if you think PHP is bad, try handling a file upload in a java servlet

Comment: Could you give me some more information. Do you use a Framework? Do you write the HTML by hand or use a generator? What kind of database are you working with? Do you use anything like ActiveRecord for your database? Help me help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to handle forms with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841213/is-there-an-easy-way-to-handle-forms-with-php)

Comment: Are you using sockpuppet accounts here? Or is this just an incredible coincidence that two almost identical questions are being asked by two different accounts?

Comment: @fireeyedboy: Thinking the same thing, even the wording is the same "handling punctuation inside a form input, manipulating strings for database insertions" - that would be an hell of a coincidence!

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP framework like [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/). It has internal [form handling solution](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.html).

Answer (score 0):

Somebody suggested PDO (PHP Data Objects) to me : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php . I have yet to check it out, but looks promising.